# PHP Files and Folders permissions under IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, wordpress, file-permissions

I have the company's **wordpress** site under **IIS 7.5** (Windows 2008R2 SP1) but I still have file access problems:

[image]

Under .NET Websites it's usual the `IIS_IUSRS` the user used by IIS to perform tasks on behalf of the website user, but **is it when using PHP as well?**

As you can see I have set the correct permissions to the `wp-content` folder and all of child folders (I did verify this).

[image]

> What am I **missing**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has nothing to do with permissions.

Check this [link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/file-path-issue-with-windows-server-and-iis), it might help.

Comment: As a link only answer it will be hard for people to upvote this.  You may want to describe the contents of the link and keep the link as a citation to your answer.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that IIS permissions are controlled through both IIS and NTFS. Make sure the directory is writable (the PUT verb) in IIS, as well as writable by the user that PHP is running under with NTFS. Both need to be working, or you'll continue to get that error.